# Python urllib2 - Freezes when connection temporarily dies

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, freeze

So, I'm working with urllib2, and it keeps freezing on a specific page. Not even Ctrl-C will cancel the operation. It's throwing no errors (I'm catching everything), and I can't figure out how to break it. Is there a timeout option for urllib2 that defaults to never?

Here's the procedure:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent':'...<chrome's user agent string>...'})
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
// p.s. I'm not installing any openers
```

Then, if the internet gets cut partway through the second line (which downloads it), even if connection is restored, this freezes the program completely.

Here's the response header I get in my browser (Chrome) from the same page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 18:12:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 247377
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "00e0dd2d7cab7cffeca0b46775e1be7e"
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow
Link: ; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: max-age=600, private, must-revalidate
Expires: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 18:12:07 GMT
X-Cacheable: NO:Not Cacheable
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Served-From-Cache: Yes
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 331ab9e1443656d5-IAD
```

p.s. The url is to a large WordPress feed which, according to the response, appears compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.getdefaulttimeout), the default timeout is, indeed, no timeout. You can specify a timeout when calling [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.urlopen) though. :)

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=30)
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked great! Thx :)